# html5 video element with "codecs selector" : fallback failing. Why?

Tags: html, video, html5-video, modernizr

I'm newish to html5 and trying to sort out the theory from the practice.

for better or worse, our transcoder only outputs .mp4 video files.

**The Theory**

I've generated html5 video element to do the following (or so I thought):

- specify an html5 video tag with a 'codec-specific' source element
- embed a link that the browser will display if it does not support either of the following:

  1. the video element
  2. the codec

The idea: if the browser does not support the "video" tag or the codec, it will display the link

**The problem**

I know that current release build of firefox (17) do not support mp4. I expected it to display the link.

However, in firefox (17), firefox displays a big black box overlaid with this message:: "No video with supported format and mime type found"

**Html**

Here's the code:

```
<video  
          <source  type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' src='/videos/33536/foo.mp4' />
          <!-- Fallback: browser should show link of it does not codec -->
          <a href='/videos/33536/foo.mp4'>
                      Click this link to view video
          </a>
</video>
```

Questions

- any way to use html5 video in this situation?
- is firefox' behavior "according so spec" or "rogue"?
- can you recommend anyway to code around this prolem (i.e. fallback gracefully using html5 video and firefox)? I've tried modernizr, but found it generated "probably" for 'Modernizr.video.mp4' and that had inconsistent results on different browsers (i.e. sometimes worked, sometimes did not)

thanks

Comment: have you tried without the type attribute, and also have you checked the MIME type your server is sending for the video (just to eliminate any strange behavior)

Answer (score 0):

The most informative source I know of for cross-browser HTML5 video is **Dive into HTML5**, there's a world of info there, including what you need for Firefox.

Check out the video chapter http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html

Good luck!